# Uploading ftp file over SSL C# StreamSocket UWP

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp, win-universal-app

I have a problem when I try to send a file in my FTP server, this problem appears only when I use a secure SSL connection. at the end of the upload the server  send me an error code "426 Data connection unexpectedly closed, upload aborted". when I use an uncrypted(PlainSocket) connection the upload is done properly.

I would appreciate your help, do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Here is some code:

```
//reading selected files from file picker

 var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
                Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

            var files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                TxtB_ProgressTitle.Text = "Uploading...";
                Grid_Progress.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                App.FtpClient.Progressing -= FtpClient_Progressing;
                App.FtpClient.Progressing += FtpClient_Progressing;
                byte[] data = null;
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    using (var reader = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    {
                        data = new byte[reader.Length];
                        int read = await reader.ReadAsync(data, 0, (int)reader.Length);
                    }
                    InitProgress((int)(data.Length / 1024), file.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        await vm.UploadFile(data, file.Name);
                    }
                    catch (FtpPermissionDeniedException exc)
                    {
                        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Permission denied", "Error uploading \"" + file.Name + "\" file");
                        await dlg.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    catch (FtpUploadException exc)
                    {
                        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Data connection unexpectedly closed, upload aborted", "Error uploading \"" + file.Name + "\" file");
                        await dlg.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    catch (FtpException exc)
                    {
                        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog(exc.Message, "Error uploading \"" + file.Name + "\" file");
                        await dlg.ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
```

Upload ftp file

```
public async Task<bool> Upload(string name, byte[] data)
    {
        var channel = await OpenChannelForDataTransfert();
        FtpResponse response = await FtpCommand.Execute(FtpTrace, FtpCommandType.UploadFile, name);
        if (response.Code == 150 || response.Code == 125)
        {
            channel.Progress += (sender, args) => OnProgress(args);
            bool dataUploaded = await channel.Upload(data);
            if (dataUploaded)
            {
                channel.Dispose();
                response = await FtpCommand.ExecuteRequest(null, FtpTrace);
                if (response.Code == 226)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (response.Code == 550)
                {
                    throw new FtpPermissionDeniedException();
                }
                else if (response.Code == 426)
                {
                    throw new FtpUploadException();
                }
            }
        }
       return false;
    }
```

opening channel for transfert:

```
private async Task<FtpChannel> OpenChannelForDataTransfert()
    {
        FtpResponse res = null;
        res = await FtpCommand.Execute(FtpTrace, FtpCommandType.BinaryMode);
        if (res.Code == 200)
        {
            res = await FtpCommand.Execute(FtpTrace, FtpCommandType.Passive);
            if (res.Code == 227)
            {
                var host = FtpParser.ParseFtpHostName(res.Message, FtpTrace);
                if (host != null)
                {
                    var channel = new FtpChannel(this, host, IsSecure);
                    if ((await channel.ConnectAsync()))
                    {
                        return channel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Uploading the file

```
public async Task<bool> Upload(byte[] data)
    {
        FtpProgressEventArgs args = new FtpProgressEventArgs();
        _TotalSize = data.Length / 1024;
        _CurrentSize = 0;
        args.TotalSize = _TotalSize;
        using (var stream = _Output.AsStreamForWrite())
        {
            using (MemoryStream d = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                int read = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_BufferSize];
                while ((read = await d.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                    _CurrentSize += read;
                    args.CurrentSize = CurrentSize;
                    OnProgress(args);
                }
                stream.Flush();
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

FtpTrace:

```
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] USER : ********
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 331 User name okay, need password. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PASS : *************
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 230 User logged in, proceed. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PBSZ 0 : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 200 PBSZ command OK. Protection buffer size set to 0. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PROT P :
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 200 PROT command OK. Using private data connection. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] OPTS UTF8 ON : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 200 OPTS UTF8 is set to ON. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PWD : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 257 "/" is current directory. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] TYPE I : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 200 Type set to I. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PASV : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 227 Entering Passive Mode (**,**,**,**,156,103) : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] MLSD : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD. : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 226 Transfer complete. 544 bytes transferred. 0.53 KB/sec. :
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
[[ParseFtpFile]]  : FooBar File
```

Le thread 0x15c8 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).

```
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] TYPE I : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 200 Type set to I. : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] PASV : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 227 Entering Passive Mode (**,**,**,**,156,106) : 
[[ExecuteRequest] Command] STOR : HomeBanner.png
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for HomeBanner.png. : 
[[ParseFtpCommand]] 426 Data connection unexpectedly closed, receive file /HomeBanner.png aborted. :
```

Thank you guys

Comment: The FTPS server you are connecting to might be expecting/requiring that the SSL session from the control connection be _reused_ for the data connection; see this post for more details: http://superuser.com/q/989048/551893

Comment: Hmmm I dont think it is possible to reuse SSL sessions using C# Streamsocket.

Comment: @Castaglia I tried to install an ftp server in my computer to test if the problem comes from the reuse for the data connection but its not...